# Class composition/reference destructs with error

Tags: c++

I am not sure what is happening, because the only error message I get is a runtime error of `Unknown signal`, which isn't a very helpful message (to me at least) which appears on my `Image` destructor.

However, when I remove/comment the line `shared_ptr<Adjust> adjust...` the error goes away and program works. Is there a different way I should be creating the reference to the composition class?

`image.h`

```cpp
#include "adjustments/adjust.h"

extern class Adjust adjust;

extern class Image {
public:
  shared_ptr<Adjust> adjust = make_shared<Adjust>(shared_ptr<Image>(this));
  virtual ~Image() = default; // Error on this line.
} image;
```

`adjustments/adjust.h`

```cpp
#include "../image.h"

using namespace std;

extern class Image image;

extern class Adjust {
private:
  shared_ptr<Image> image;
public:
  Adjust(shared_ptr<Image> image) {
    this->image = image;
  }
  virtual ~Adjust() = default;
} adjust;
```

The image class is created like this (very simplified):

```cpp
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Load jpeg using libjpeg (this is done in a Jpeg class) and returned to main.
  shared_ptr<Image> image = make_shared<Image>();
}
```

Comment: `shared_ptr<Image>(this)` is almost always wrong, but especially when the instance is static to boot. Are you new to C++ by any chance? It is without exaggeration the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Picking it up as one goes along is not feasible.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, I am new (day 4).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Comment: And a follow-on, `auto` makes a lot of sense for your error-prone line as it will reduce the repitition without losing any clarity.

Comment: Then I recommend you take a detour and go over something like [A Tour of C++](https://www.amazon.com/Tour-2nd-Depth-Bjarne-Stroustrup/dp/0134997832), it's by Bjarne himself, covers an up to date standard, and is geared at experienced devs in about 200 pages. It removes many of the sharp edges one is bound to encounter while figuring it out in an unstructrued manner. We also have a [curated book list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/817643) for further reference about best practices and useful idioms.

Comment: Thanks for the link(s) I will check them out.